# Where can I install a database in a client PC and use its path as a connection string?

Tags: c#, ms-access, installation

I have created a software complaint tracking system in C#, using Access Databases.

Basically, it's done, but I am questioning where to install it on my client's PC?
I tried to install it in the DataDirectory, but I'm getting an error with that:

> Operation must use updateable query in application.

My Connection String is `Datasource=|DataDirectory|\\convert.accdb`
I created the setup project by installshield

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: show us the code and connection string

Comment: It seems that there's a problem with permissions. How is the application installed / How do you create the setup? (ClickOnce, WiX, VDPROJ, ...)?

Comment: i have created setup project by installshield

Comment: software installed perfectly but

Comment: When i insert data to the database it has no effect

Comment: and shows error described above

Comment: My Connection String is Datasource=|DataDirectory|\\convert.accdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a ConnectionString with **|DataDirectory|**, it's very likely that the database file is in the programs folder and due to security permissions the user can't write to the file.

So you should modify the location where the database file is installed (APPDATA if it's per user, see below).
The connection can stay the same if you add the following code to tell your application that the placeholder **|DataDirectory|** should be replaced with the APPDATA-folder

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

### |DataDirectory|

> |DataDirectory| (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string that indicates the path to the database. It eliminates the need to hard-code the full path which leads to several problems as the full path to the database could be serialized in different places. DataDirectory also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy an application.
>
> To set the DataDirectory property, call the `AppDomain.SetData` method. If you do not set the DataDirectory property, the following default rules will be applied to access the database folder:
>
> - **For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder.**
> - For applications that are running under ClickOnce, the database folder uses the specific data folder that is created.

[Source: SQL Server Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce) (Emphasis added by me)

---

### Locations for installation

> 10.1 Your app must be installed in the Program Files folder by default
>   For native 32-bit and 64-bit apps in %ProgramFiles%, and %ProgramFiles(x86)% for 32-bit apps running on x64. **User data or app data must never be stored in this location because of the security permissions configured for this folder.**
>
> 10.3 Your app data, which must be shared among users on the computer, should be stored within **ProgramData**
>
> 10.4 Your app’s data that is exclusive to a specific user and that is not to be shared with other users of the computer, must be stored in **Users\<username>\AppData**

[Source: Certification requirements for Windows Desktop Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674655(v=vs.85).aspx) 
(Emphasis added by me)

Comment: and what is my connection string

Comment: I edited my answer and added some information about correct locations for installed files and how to modify the program. The connection doesn't need to be modified

Comment: my actual database file convert.accdb is in project file (Path is E:\Projects\Convert.accdb in my pc) and when i install the application i need to copy this database to appdata folder or what?

Comment: Well it depends on how it should be used. If E:\ is a network share that your users have and they all access the same file, you need to modify your connectionstring that it uses the file on E:\. If every user has his own file, it needs to be copied to the users appdata folder as described above

Comment: let me explain this

Comment: I am developer i have created application in my laptop and in e: my actual database file is saved now my software is completed and i want to install this application to client pc. so,i just want to use database that is also store d in client and used for data operation

Comment: So every user has his own database file. That means that it (the accdb file) needs to be installed to the user's appdata folder as described above (instead of the installation folder of the application, where it is installed now).

Comment: Thank You Stephen Baur. You are genious